# Flexibly align date formats in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a df with many columns. For each column I identify the type, and pull out insights.
For instance, columns I identified as date (using `parse(string, fuzzy=fuzzy)`) are sent to the function below:

```
def find_date_insights(df: pd.DataFrame, col: str) -> str:
    date_df = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
    return f"{date_df.min()} - {date_df.max()}"
```

Problem starts when I have a mix of date formats in the column, primarily when empty values are marked as dash (`-`) and when some values are in string format (2021-01-01) while some are in number format (44197). I tried adding `, errors='coerce'`, but then values that are clearly not dates where considered as dates. I do want to function to fail if I misidentified the field type.
So, I tried accounting for the specific case described above in the following manner:

```
def find_date_insights(df: pd.DataFrame, col: str) -> str:
    try:
        date_df = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
    except:
        date_df[col] = (datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) + timedelta(df[col].astype(int))).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        date_df = pd.to_datetime(date_df[col])
    return f"{date_df.min()} - {date_df.max()}"
```

But now rightfully date columns are getting an error for legit dates...
I'm pretty much lost and would appreciate you assistance.
Thanks!

Below you can find a handy script to play with:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np


def find_date_insights(df: pd.DataFrame, col: str) -> str:
    date_df = df[col]
    date_df[col] = np.where(df[col].astype(str) == '-', '', df[col].astype(str))
    try:
        date_df = pd.to_datetime(date_df[col])
    except:
        print('dang')
        date_df[col] = (datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) + timedelta(df[col].astype(int))).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        date_df = pd.to_datetime(date_df[col])

    return f"{date_df.min()} - {date_df.max()}"


if __name__ == '__main__':
     d = {'bad_date': ["44198", "4952837597","32000"],
          'good_date': ["-", "2021-01-01", "44197"],
          'clear_date': ["2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-01-03"]}
     df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
     for c in df.columns:
          try:
               print(find_date_insights(df,c))
          except Exception as e:
               print(c+": "+str(e))
```

I expect `bad_date` to fail, and the other two to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up narrowing down the problem definition, posted it here:
[Converting pandas column to date, with many type of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70368195/converting-pandas-column-to-date-with-many-type-of-dates)
and used the answer provided. Thanks!