# Converting pandas column to date, with many type of dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How would you convert the below date column into a single formatted date column?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'datecol': ["-",
                                    "44198",
                                    "2021/01/01", 
                                    "14.04.20",
                                    "2021-13-03"]})
```

`print(df.dropna())` should return the result below:

```
      datecol
0  2021-01-02
1  2021-01-01
2  2020-04-14
3  2021-03-13
```

Comment: "44198" is not a recognised date format in Python. You presumably are getting this from Excel, where the number represents the days after 31 Dec 1899

Comment: I know, I'm doing a reduction for a broader problem. In the original question, I try using something like ```(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) + timedelta(df[col].astype(int))).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")```, but I can't account for any possible format out there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Convert all valid datetime formats using `pd.to_datetime`, specifying formats for unrecognised formats
2. Convert all integer (Excel) dates.
3. Combine both with `fillna`

```
parsed = pd.to_datetime(df["datecol"], errors="coerce").fillna(pd.to_datetime(df["datecol"],format="%Y-%d-%m",errors="coerce"))
ordinal = pd.to_numeric(df["datecol"], errors="coerce").apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp("1899-12-30")+pd.Timedelta(x, unit="D"))

df["datecol"] = parsed.fillna(ordinal)

>>> df
     datecol
0        NaT
1 2021-01-02
2 2021-01-01
3 2020-04-14
4 2021-03-13
```

Answer (score 2):

If a column contains multiple formats, you're going to need to parse the column multiple times with the different formats and use `combine_first` to combine the resulting information. Because we specify `errors='coerce'` the date format should only match *one* of the formats.

The other small complication is that some of your formats require you to just specify the `format` argument, but others would require the `origin` and `unit` parameters. We can take care of this passing a dict of `kwargs` to the `pd.to_datetime` function.

Note any numeric values will work with `origin` and `unit` so you can't use this method if your date column had values that represented different units with different offsets in the same column. You would need to provide other logic to indicate which units and offsets are pertinent to which rows in that case.

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce 

kwl = [{'format': '%Y/%m/%d'},
       {'format': '%d.%m.%y'},
       {'format': '%Y-%d-%m'},
       {'format': '%Y/%m/%d'},
       {'unit': 'd', 'origin': '1899-12-30'}]]

l = []
for kwargs in kwl:
    if 'unit' in kwargs.keys():
        s = pd.to_numeric(df['datecol'], errors='coerce')
    else:
        s = df['datecol']
        
    l.append(pd.to_datetime(s, errors='coerce', **kwargs))

result = reduce(lambda l,r: l.combine_first(r), l)
```

---

```
print(result)
#0          NaT
#1   2021-01-02
#2   2021-01-01
#3   2020-04-14
#4   2021-03-13
Name: datecol, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```